# passing an array structure as an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm having trouble passing a structure array as a parameter of a function

```
struct Estructure{
 int a;
 int b;
};
```

and a function

```
Begining(Estructure &s1[])
{
   //modifi the estructure s1
};
```

and the main would be something like this

```
int main()
{
  Estructure m[200];
  Begining(m);
};
```

is this valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Begining(struct Estructure s1[])
{
   //modifi the estructure s1
};

int main()
{
  struct Estructure m[200];
  Begining(m);
  return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to typedef your struct, and you should pass the array to it; pass by reference does not work in C.

```
typedef struct Estructure{
 int a;
 int b;
} Estructure_s;

Begining(Estructure_s s1[])
{
   //modify the estructure s1
}

int main()
{
  Estructure_s m[200];
  Begining(m);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
struct Estructure{
 int a;
 int b;
};

Begining(struct Estructure *s1)
{
   //modify the estructure s1
}

int main()
{
  struct Estructure m[200];
  Begining(m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

typedef struct { int a; int b;} Estructure;

void Begining(Estructure *svector)
{
   svector[0].a =1;
}

Comment: i keep getting the following error:

tp1.c:96: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘Medico’

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct{
 int a;
 int b;
} Estructure;

void Begining(Estructure s1[], int length)
//Begining(Estructure *s1)  //both are same
{
   //modify the estructure s1
};

int main()
{
  Estructure m[200];
  Begining(m, 200);
  return 0;
};
```

*Note: Its better to add `length` to your function `Beginning`.*

Answer (score 0):

Either stick the work struct in front of Estructure or typedef it to some other type and use that.  Also pass by reference doesn't exist in C, pass a pointer instead if you wish.  Perhaps:

```
void Begining(struct Estructure **s1)
{
   s1[1]->a = 0;
}
```

Not quite the same as an array, but this should work in C land and it passes a pointer for efficiency.